# Timestamp.now() auto date time for messenger

Tags: flutter, date, ntp

I'm trying to create an app that allows users to chat with each other and to order the messages i'm using Timestamp.now() ( that works fine ) but the problem is that if the user dont have auto date time turned on on the phone and the hour is different ( like 1 minute ) the messages order is totally messy. I've tried to use NTP.now() but it not worked, even if i set an offset and add to datetime. Any sugestions or solution for this problem? In this case, i used offset using time.google.com as server ( maybe that's my error?) because after the first message the date time is the same for all messages from user

Answer (score 0):

Use any api service like
[worldtimeapi.org](http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/asia/kolkata)

And get a unified time based on one server.

Comment: If i use any api like worldtimeapi it will give me real time date time and i can use it without delay between requests?

Comment: There will be a small delay but you will get the all users in the same timeline. It won't be extremely off like hours apart. You can save everybody's time in UTC